# The Uninstall section of my .INF

Tags: windows, device-driver

I'm working on extending an existing USB device driver, and have been struggling learn how the .INF file works.  I believe that I have it right now, the driver installs and works.  It also shows up in the "Add/Remove Programs" list.

I find that when I uninstall the driver from Add/Remove, it seems to do little if anything.  This was in the .INF as I inherited it:

```
[myUninstall]
DelReg = myDelReg

[MyDelReg]
HKLM, "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\myName"
```

I can find no other references, not even where "myName" is installed in the registry Uninstall.

I've changed the .INF to have this:

```
[DefaultUninstall]
myUninstall

[myUninstall]
DelFiles = ... a list of files ...
DelDirs  = UNINST.Dirs
DelReg   = UNINST.Regs
Cleanup  = 1

[UNINST.Dirs]
%16422%\%InstallDir%

[UNINST.Regs]
myDev.AddReg
myDev.CommonRegs


[myDev.AddReg]      ; same definition used for installing
HKR,,Drivers,Subclasses,,"wave,midi,mixer,aux"
...

[myDev,CommonRegs]  ; same definition used for installing
HKR, Parameters, BufferSize, 0x0010001, 256
...
```

Still, whether I uninstall from the Control Panel Add/Remove programs or do it from the device manager, the system doesn't complain and nothing seems to happen.  I've looked at the output of "dpinst /c" and the setupapi.log, and neither tell me much.  dpinst shows no error but is clearly not even trying to execute my uninstall section.

I find a lot of verbiage online and examples of uninstall sections, but very little in the way of explanation.  I did stumble across one sentence in 1 forum today that implied that PnP device .INF's don't use Uninstall.  Perhaps this is my issue?

1. am I wrong in thinking that I can have Uninstall in this .INF?
2. is there some other way to tell what is happening?
3. is my only recourse to write a separate uninstaller?

Answer (score 0):

AFIK, the INF files do not participate in uninstallation.

You will need to write a separate uninstaller if you want to perform proper cleanup.

Further note that with Vista and beyond, Windows also includes a Driver Store, where it silently copies the driver package (inf and files references from the inf). If you want to perform a full cleanup, the driver store should also be cleaned up.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `DefaultUninstall` is a standard section in the way `DefaultInstall` is. Often you will see the `UninstallString` ARP entry just calling `DefaultUninstall` by name.

The documentation in this area is pretty bad and there is a split between the basic SetupAPI/SetupX INF files and the Advanced INF files (AdvPack).

The only 3rd-party exception I know of is TweakUI.inf from the Windows 95 PowerToys.

It has parts that look like this:

```
...

[Optional Components]
TweakUIInstall

[TweakUIInstall]
CopyFiles = ...
AddReg    = ...
Ini2Reg   = ...
...
InstallType    = 10 ;Typical, Custom.
Uninstall      = DefaultUnInstall

[DefaultUnInstall]
DelFiles  = ...
DelReg    = ...
```

But I think that only works with the optional components feature, not basic uninstallation. TweakUI v1.33 (Tweakui.exe SFX archive) has some more NT related entries and I believe the way it writes the `UninstallString` for NT even writes the wrong INF section. Wrong or not, it manually has to specify a INF section for normal uninstall.